# Retry testing sites after timeout error in Watir

Tags: ruby, timeout, watir, rescue

I am going through a list of sites and going to each one using Watir to look for something in the source code of each page. However, after about 20 or 30 sites, the browser times out when loading a certain page and it breaks my script and I get this error:

> rbuf_fill: execution expired (Timeout::Error)

I am trying to implement a way to detect when it times out and then restart testing the sites from where it left off but am having trouble.
This is my code:

```
ie = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :profile => "default"
testsite_array = Array.new
y=0
File.open('topsites.txt').each do |line|
testsite_array[y] = line
y=y+1
end
total = testsite_array.length
count = 0
begin
    while count <= total
        site = testsite_array[count]
        ie.goto site
        if ie.html.include? 'teststring'
            puts site + ' yes'
        else
            puts site + ' no'
        end

rescue
retry
    count = count+1
    end
end
ie.close
```

Comment: When you say "restart testing the sites", do you just mean you want to skip the site that failed and move on to the next one? Or you want to retry the failed site and then move on to the next one?

Comment: I'd like to retry the failed site and then move on to the next one! That would solve timeout error issues. Down the line, I would like to implement skipping the site if it's failed multiple times such as in the case of a nonexistent domain name!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop can be:

```
#Use Ruby's method for iterating through the array
testsite_array.each do |site|
    attempt = 1
    begin
        ie.goto site
        if ie.html.include? 'teststring'
            puts site + ' yes'
        else
            puts site + ' no'
        end 
    rescue
        attempt += 1

        #Retry accessing the site or stop trying
        if attempt > MAX_ATTEMPTS
            puts site + ' site failed, moving on'
        else
            retry
        end
    end
end
```